# Pyspark sample value from array column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have my spark dataframe as follow:

```
target_id   other_ids
3733345     [3731634, 3729995, 3728014, 3708332, 3720...
3725312     [3711541, 3726052, 3733763, 900056057, 371...
3717114     [3701718, 3713481, 3715433, 3714825, 3731...
3408996     [3405896, 3250400, 3237054, 3242492, 3256...
3354970     [3354969, 3347893, 3348168, 3353273, 3356...
```

I want to first shuffle the elements in the arrays in of `other_ids` column and then create a new column `new_id` where I sample an id from the array of `other_ids`  column where `target_id`  is not in `other_ids`.
Final result:

```
target_id   other_ids                                      new_id
3733345     [3731634, 3729995, 3728014, 3708332, 3720...   3708332
3725312     [3711541, 3726052, 3733763, 900056057, 371...  900056057
3717114     [3701718, 3713481, 3715433, 3714825, 3731...   3250400
3408996     [3405896, 3250400, 3237054, 3242492, 3256...   3237054
3354970     [3354969, 3347893, 3348168, 3353273, 3356...   3353273
```

Any suggestions? Thnaks.

Comment: Can you share your output dataset? I kind of lost here!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this -

```py
df = df.withColumn('new_id', F.element_at(
    F.shuffle(
        F.array_except(F.col('other_ids'), F.array(F.col('target_id')))
    ),
    1
))
```

Comment: That is actually a good and simple solution. I was wondering do you know how to make the `shuffle` deterministic?

Comment: `shuffle` doesn't take seed.  If you want it to be deterministic, do you need to pick from random position in an array or can it be always `element_at` 1 without `shuffle`?  The other option I can think of is to use `udf` with `randint`.